# Oracle SQL: getting all row maximum number from specific multiple criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table named foo:

```
ID | D1  | D2  | D3 |
---------------------
1 | 47  | 3   | 71 |
2 | 47  | 98  | 82 | 
3 | 0   | 99  | 3  |
4 | 3   | 100 | 6  |
5 | 48  | 10  | 3  |
6 | 49  | 12  | 4  |
```

I want to run a select query and have the results show like this

```
ID | D1  | D2  | D3 | Result |
------------------------------
 1 | 47  | 3   | 71 | D3     |
 2 | 47  | 98  | 82 | D2     | 
 3 | 0   | 99  | 3  | D2     |
 4 | 3   | 100 | 6  | D2     |
 5 | 48  | 10  | 3  | D1     |
 6 | 49  | 12  | 4  | D1     |
```

So, basically I want to get Maximum value between D1, D2, D3 column divided by id.
As You may seen , ID 1 have D3 in the Result column since Maximum value between 
D1 : D2 : D3

That Means 4 : 3 : 71 , Max value is 71. Thats Why The Result show 'D3'

Is there a way to do this in a sql query ?

Thanks!

Comment: mysql or oracle ? tag it properly.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty : Its actually Oracle database, but I want to know how to do it in SQL query too ?

Comment: @Strawberry : What do you mean sir ? I'm sorry I didn't get it

Comment: Normalize your data. Normalization is *THE* fundamental concept underlying Relational Databases. It's important to "get it". The other answers provided here are simply whitewash.

Comment: @Strawberry While normalization is certainly a core concept of relational databases, this question is not directly related to it. Of course you could add a detail table for the D1, D2 and D3 values, but without more information about the kind of data being stored, it's impossible to say whether this is more sensible or not.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Maybe, but I'll bet you a beer I'm right. (And a detail table is not required - or, rather, this could be it. All that's required is a normalized design)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following - a normalized approach...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL 
,d INT NOT NULL
,val INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,d)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,47),
(2,1,47),
(3,1,0),
(4,1,3),
(5,1,48),
(6,1,49),
(1,2,3),
(2,2,98),
(3,2,99),
(4,2,100),
(5,2,10),
(6,2,12),
(1,3,71),
(2,3,82),
(3,3,3),
(4,3,6),
(5,3,3),
(6,3,4);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+---+-----+
| id | d | val |
+----+---+-----+
|  1 | 1 |  47 |
|  1 | 2 |   3 |
|  1 | 3 |  71 |
|  2 | 1 |  47 |
|  2 | 2 |  98 |
|  2 | 3 |  82 |
|  3 | 1 |   0 |
|  3 | 2 |  99 |
|  3 | 3 |   3 |
|  4 | 1 |   3 |
|  4 | 2 | 100 |
|  4 | 3 |   6 |
|  5 | 1 |  48 |
|  5 | 2 |  10 |
|  5 | 3 |   3 |
|  6 | 1 |  49 |
|  6 | 2 |  12 |
|  6 | 3 |   4 |
+----+---+-----+

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN  
     ( SELECT id,MAX(val) max_val FROM my_table GROUP BY id) y 
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.max_val = x.val;
+----+---+-----+
| id | d | val |
+----+---+-----+
|  1 | 3 |  71 |
|  2 | 2 |  98 |
|  3 | 2 |  99 |
|  4 | 2 | 100 |
|  5 | 1 |  48 |
|  6 | 1 |  49 |
+----+---+-----+
```

(This is intended as a MySQL solution - I'm not familiar with ORACLE syntax, so apologies if this doesn't port)

Does this answer your comment?

```
SELECT x.* , y.max_val
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT id,MAX(val) max_val FROM my_table GROUP BY id) y
    ON y.id = x.id ;
+----+---+-----+---------+
| id | d | val | max_val |
+----+---+-----+---------+
|  1 | 1 |  47 |      71 |
|  1 | 2 |   3 |      71 |
|  1 | 3 |  71 |      71 |
|  2 | 1 |  47 |      98 |
|  2 | 2 |  98 |      98 |
|  2 | 3 |  82 |      98 |
|  3 | 1 |   0 |      99 |
|  3 | 2 |  99 |      99 |
|  3 | 3 |   3 |      99 |
|  4 | 1 |   3 |     100 |
|  4 | 2 | 100 |     100 |
|  4 | 3 |   6 |     100 |
|  5 | 1 |  48 |      48 |
|  5 | 2 |  10 |      48 |
|  5 | 3 |   3 |      48 |
|  6 | 1 |  49 |      49 |
|  6 | 2 |  12 |      49 |
|  6 | 3 |   4 |      49 |
+----+---+-----+---------+
```

Comment: Thank You sir for the answer, I am really appreciate it. but what am i intended to do is, gather all maximum value for each row, i mean if you were looking at your data above.. <br/> There are 18 rows counted , so if we calculated the maximum value of each attribute, it should contains 18 row too.

Answer (score 3):

For Oracle please try this one

```
select foo.*, case when greatest(d1, d2, d3) = d1 then 'D1'
                   when greatest(d1, d2, d3) = d2 then 'D2'
                   when greatest(d1, d2, d3) = d3 then 'D3'
              end result
from foo
```

Comment: If the input data may contain NULL values, it would be wise to add some NVL() calls - greatest() returns NULL if one of the arguments is NULL.

Comment: it is up to topic starter

Comment: Could You please kindly tell me how to use that NVL() calls that you mention above ? since there is a possibility that data value is null in some column.

Comment: sure, what result do you expect if some field contains null? in query above if one or more fields are null result is null. you can and `nvl` for replace null with some value, e.g. `nvl(d1, 0)`